# Struts2 - Call Javascript function during Iteration on JSP

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, jsp, struts2

I have a project where i need to display markers on map (Google Maps) based on longlat values which are fetched from database. I'm successful in displaying the longlat values on table but not on the map because the javascript call doesn't work even on simple alert. I'm using struts2 iterator for this and I've put the javascript during iteration. This is the code I have. Some codes omitted for brevity. Can anyone help me with this?

```
function plotOnMap(lat,long) { 
alert(long + "," + lat);
}
.
.
.
// code for struts iteration
<s:iterator value="myBeanList" status="myBeanStatus" var="roamerBean" >
<tr>
<s:if test="#myBeanStatus.even == true">
    <s:if test="#myBeanStatus.first == true">     
          <td style="background: #CCCCCC" onshow="javascript:plotOnMap(<s:property value="#roamerBean.latitude" />,<s:property value="#roamerBean.longitude" />)"><s:property value="#roamerBean.cellId"/></td>
          <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property value="#roamerBean.cellName"/></td>
          <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property value="#roamerBean.longitude"/></td>
          <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property value="#roamerBean.latitude" /></td>        
    </s:if>
   </s:if>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: The `id` attribute must be unique.

Comment: id on the <td> tag @Aleksandr M ?

Comment: There is not td tag with id in your question. ;)

Comment: There is no id on the <td> tag, and id will be unique because of the second check (that makes the first useless): only the first will be taken. There is not even the need for an iterator then. This is a complete mess :D

Comment: Sorry @AleksandrM, i didnt got what you're trying to imply. What i'm specifically asking is how can i call a simple javascript function within the iteration.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, i omitted some code just to show the part where I am calling the javascript, which is isn't working :D

Comment: And I'm telling you why it isn't working. You are trying to get element by id, but you have multiple elements with same id. This is wrong.

Comment: I see @AleksandrM, so can you tell me how i can include the listindex as the unique id identifier for the hidden fields?

Comment: If you are using script function in `onshow` what stops your from passing arguments to it?

Comment: @AleksandrM : how can he has duplicated `id` with `<s:if test="#myBeanStatus.first == true">` ? The iterator is useless, but with the code AS IS, `id` are unique...

Comment: @AndreaLigios: :D Oops. user1708189: You can ignore what I've said that you have multiple elements with same id, unless you use different code as shown.

Comment: @all, I've modified the code and removed the hidden fields, this time passing parameter values directly to the javascript function but still not a success. Is placing the javascript code within the <td onshow="javascript:plotOnMap('%{#roamerBean.latitude}','%{#roamerBean.longitude}')"> tag correct?

Comment: No use `<s:property>` tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM, doesn't work either

Comment: edit your question with the new code, instead of saying it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you doing it in iterator?

Comment: @RomanC, because i have a list of bean object which contains longlat values that's why i need to iterate over them to get the longlat values then plot it on map. Code shown were just mere part of the whole code.

Comment: @user1708189: With `#myBeanStatus.first == true` you are not really iterating values. So maybe you can post a real code or explain what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a different approach. I've put the part where i'm going to determine the starting & ending longlats inside the action class, of which the position came from the database (starting point is the first row while the ending point is the last row). Thanks for your effort all. I will mark this thread now as answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess [`onshow` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#scripting.attr.onshow) is definitely *not* what you think it is:

> **onshow** : User requested the element be shown as a context menu.

With a bit of imagination, what you want to do is to call `plotOnMap` when hovering over the table's row... then simply use an iterator and the well known [`onmouseover` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#scripting.attr.onmouseover):

> **onmouseover** : User moved pointer into boundaries of element or one of its descendant elements.

Also avoid inline styling, and put this in head section (or better in a CSS) to reduce the noise in the code:

```xml
<style>
    tr.ccc > td { 
        background-color: #CCCCCC;  
    }
</style>
```

body:

```xml
<s:iterator value="myBeanList">
    <tr class = "ccc" 
  onmouseover = "javascript:plotOnMap(<s:property value='latitude' />,<s:property value='longitude' />);">
        <td><s:property value="cellId"    /></td>
        <td><s:property value="cellName"  /></td>
        <td><s:property value="longitude" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="latitude"  /></td>        
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

---

**EDIT**

> yes, tried that and it's working, thanks. I can now plot the longlat
>   with markers on the map. What i'm struggling now is tracking which of
>   the values are the start and end points so that i can show via the
>   info window.

I've no clue on what the *info window* is, but you can get starting latitude longitude at any moment with s:property pointing to the first element. Eg:

```
alert('Starting latitude  : <s:property value="%{myBeanList[0].latitude}"/>'  );
alert('Starting longitude : <s:property value="%{myBeanList[0].longitude}"/>' );
```

Comment: no values were displayed. Still javascript function was not called.

Comment: what do you suggest then if I'm not going to use onshow? onload doesn't work either on <table>, <tr>, and <td> tags? As soon as the page shown, I want the map to be filled with longlat values from myBean but not using <body onload="plotOnMap"> because I want to determine which are the starting and end longlat points.

Comment: You can *anytime* know which are the starting and ending longlat points... you can also use the above iterator (without the html code) in a script block, in a function called by body onload, for example. Seriously, I'm missing something here. Can you explain when and how do you need to track the starting and ending points ?

Comment: yes, tried that and it's working, thanks. I can now plot the longlat with markers on the map. What i'm struggling now is tracking which of the values are the start and end points so that i can show via the info window.

Comment: Hi @AndreaLigios, i've tried a different approach. I've put the part where i'm going to determine the starting & ending longlats inside the action class, of which the position came from the database (starting point is the first row while the ending point is the last row). Thanks for your effort all. I will mark this thread now as answered. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax 
`javascript:plotOnMap(%{#attr.roamerBean.latitude}`
I have used this at many places but without the var attribute in iterator tag. It should work fine with the "var" attribute also.